# Database Design + Rails associations with :through using metadata

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, activerecord, data-modeling

Here is the scenario: I am building a system that will let users search for each other based on their skill sets.

- Users have skills. Skills are universal objects and are shared amongst users.
- Users have the following metadata associated with skills: level and interest
- Each user can create their own categories under which they can organize their skills (e.g. one user might have the skill "Saas" under "Front-End Development" and another under "Web Development")

I have 4 tables: Users, Skills, Categories & Skillsets

Assuming that John Doe (username: "johndoe") has the following categories and skill set:

Category: Front-End
Skills: HAML, SASS/SCSS, CoffeeScript, Javascript, jQuery

Category: Back-End
Skills: Ruby, Ruby on Rails, node.js

I'd like to be able to perform the following operations:

```
user = User.where(:username => "johndoe").first

user.categories
# returns a list of the user's categories

user.skills
# returns a list of the user's skills

user.category.where(name => "Front-End").first.skills
# => returns list of skills in the "Front-End" category

user.skills.where(:name => "HAML").first.category
# returns "Front-End" category

# adds a skill without assigning it to a category
user.skills << skill_object
user.skills.last.level = 9
user.skills.last.interest = 6
user.skills.last.save

# adds a skill while assigning it to a category
user.category.skills << skill_object
user.category.skills.last.level = 9
user.category.skills.last.interest = 6
user.category.skills.last.save
```

And in order to find users by skill:

```
skill = Skill.where(:name => "Javascript").first

skill.users
# returns users possessing skill
```

I've been playing around with my models for a while but not quite getting to behave as I'd like them to. I need a fresh perspective -  Any pointers / suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Ruby, but from a relational db perspective, I'd probably just create a special, hardcoded, category field for each user: `Uncategorized`.

Then, when you add skills, they either go in a specified cateogory, or the default uncategorized one for that user.  Outside of that one "special" record for each user, everything else would work perfectly no matter which skill or category you're looking at, and you can leave all your constraints in place without having to worry about null values.

```
UserID, User
1, me

CategoryID, UserID, Category
1,1,Uncategorized
2,1,Web GUI

SkillID, Skill
1,Javascript
2,Knitting

SkillID, CategoryID, Level, Interest
1,2,10,75
2,1,50,1
```

Depending on how you use Level and Interest, I'd also consider making them lookup tables to give meaning to the values from a database perspective (and help populate drop down lists).
etc.